# how to load a c string from a file

Tags: c, c-strings, cfile

my code keeps throwing a segmentation fault from internal c libraries, my code is the following:

```
        char *vertexShaderCode = (char *)calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
        FILE *shaderFile;

        shaderFile = fopen("./shaders/vertex.glsl", "r");

        if(shaderFile)
        {
            //TODO: load file
            for (char *line; !feof(shaderFile);)
            {
                fgets(line, 1024, shaderFile);
                strcat(vertexShaderCode, line);
            }
```

it is meant to load all the data from a file as a c string, line by line. can anyone help?

Comment: [`while (!feof(file))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/), even when disguised, [is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/)

Comment: TODO: check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: _" keeps throwing errors"_: which errors? Post the __verbatim__ error messages in your question. You can [Edit] your question.

Comment: i keep getting a segmentation fault from my program, i edited that into the question

Comment: 1. do what I told you in my second comment. 2. eliminate the wrong `feof` as per the first comment. 3. make sure you allocate enough memory with `calloc`, if your file is too long, you'll have a buffer overflow which often manifests itself as segmentation fault.

Comment: i checked for the fopen error, that is not the issue, and i fixed the segmentation fault. I have no idea how though... my code is now in the question

Comment: I concur with @Jabberwocky, most likely your file is more than 1024 characters and you aren't calling `realloc` on your buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
char *vertexShaderCode = (char *)calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
FILE *shaderFile;

shaderFile = fopen("./shaders/vertex.glsl", "r");
if (shaderFile == NULL)
{
   printf("Could not open file, bye.");
   exit(1);
}

char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), shaderFile) != NULL)
{
   strcat(vertexShaderCode, line);
}
```

You still need to make your that there is no buffer overflow. Possibly you need touse `realloc` in order to expand the buffer if the initial length of the buffer is too small. I leave this as an exercise to you.

---

Your wrong code:

```
    char *vertexShaderCode = (char *)calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
    FILE *shaderFile;

    shaderFile = fopen("./shaders/vertex.glsl", "r");  // no check if fopen fails

    for (char *line; !feof(shaderFile);)   // wrong usage of feof
    {                                      // line is not initialized
                                           // that's the main problem
        fgets(line, 1024, shaderFile);
        strcat(vertexShaderCode, line);    // no check if buffer overflows
    }
```

Comment: how would i account for the buffer overflow, i don't know how to do that.

Comment: @ShadowLynch your code is basically accumulating information in the `vertexShaderCode` buffer whose size if 1024. If you continue to add information in that buffer it will overflow, just like if you continue to pour water in a glass when it it full, the water will overflow. Hint: use a pencil and a piece of paper. Hint 2: use the `realloc` function to expand your buffer if it gets too small.

Comment: In the while loop you could check that `strlen(line) + strlen(vertexShaderCode)` is less than 1024. If not it could be a good place where to add realloc (or at least a warning printf).